# integrating javascript time with content in marquee tag to show on the same line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, marquee

Can't seem to get this javascript clock to appear on the same line as the content i would like scrolling in my marquee. At the moment the text I would like as content following the time appears on a line underneath? Is there a way to display the text content next to the time on the same line?
Thank you

```html
<body>
<header id="pageHeader">
<marquee style="
width: 100%;
/* position: fixed; */
display: block;
background: #000;
z-index: 999999999999;
margin: 0;
font-size:18px;
color: #FFB6C1;
left: 0;
"> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt">  </div>
CONTENT TEXT TO FOLLOW THE TIME / WRITING HERE
</body>
</html>  </marquee>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just added `display: inline-block` to your `div` so it doesn't take up the entire row space.

```css
#txt {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<body>
<header id="pageHeader">
<marquee style="
width: 100%;
/* position: fixed; */
display: block;
background: #000;
z-index: 999999999999;
margin: 0;
font-size:18px;
color: #FFB6C1;
left: 0;
"> <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    var s = today.getSeconds();
    m = checkTime(m);
    s = checkTime(s);
    document.getElementById('txt').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m + ":" + s;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);
}
function checkTime(i) {
    if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};  // add zero in front of numbers < 10
    return i;
}
</script>
</head>

<body onload="startTime()">

<div id="txt">  </div>
CONTENT TEXT TO FOLLOW THE TIME / WRITING HERE
</body>
</html>  </marquee>
```